# Howler.js + Cordova - can't find/load sound files on Android

Tags: android, cordova, howler.js

I have a multi-platform *Cordova 6.2.0* project that works just fine the way it does. To play, modify and mix sounds I'm using *Howler.js 2.0*.
On all platforms except Android it works fine. On Android I can't load sound files, the logcat shows me "file not found".

```
function loadSound(url) {
    var deviceURL = (device.platform = "Android") ?
        "/android_asset/www/" + url :
        url;
    return new Howl([src: [deviceURL], onload: onSoundLoad, onerror: onSoundError);
}
```

When I replace the `new Howl()` call with an according `new Media` call, using *cordova-plugin-media*, the files can be loaded but I lose all Howler goodness like mixing, or loading callbacks.

Omitting the Android-specific prefix `"/android_asset/www/"` won't help either.

To avoid any decoding issues, I also tested with uncompressed *.wav* files.

Do I have to use different paths? Do I need any permissions?

There are similar questions here already, but I feel none has been answered sufficiently.